# AngularFire2 Query List Get Child Values

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have the following data structure:

```
{
 "users" : {
    "AXLKSD9ASLKDJJ0991" : {
      "authType" : "ap1",
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "red"
    },
    "A778ASDUASDJ8AS8DA" : {
      "authType" : "ap1",
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "blue"
    },
    "ASD88ASD8ASD8HAS8D" : {
      "authType" : "ap2",
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "red"
    }
  }
}
```

I created a service dedicated to Firebase, which has the following method. This successfully returns the users into my component:

firebase.service.ts:

```
userList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

getUsersByAuthType(authType: string) {
  return this.userList = this.afDb.list('/users', {
    preserveSnapshot: true,
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'authProvider',
        equalTo: authType
    }
  });
}
```

admin.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-administration',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdministrationComponent implements OnInit {
  usersData: any;

  constructor(
      private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1');
  }

}
```

admin.component.html:

```
<h2>test 1</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user.enabled }}</li>
</ul>

<br /><br /><br />

<h2>test 2</h2>
{{ usersData | async | json }}

<br /><br /><br />

<h2>test 3</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user.key }}</li>
</ul>
```

The "test 1" does not show anything..

The "test 2" shows the whole returned json object:

```
{ "authType" : "ap1", "enabled" : true, "color" : "red" }, { "authType" : "ap1", "enabled" : true, "color" : "blue" }
```

The "test 3" shows me the keys.

I've tried a number of other ways but without success. The reference documentation suggests what I am doing is OK

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md

Ideas?

**Update**

I also added the following to admin.component.html:

```
<br /><br /><br />

<h2>test 4</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ (user | json) }}</li>
</ul>
```

This also resulted in the following output in the rendered page:

- { "authType" : "ap1", "enabled" : true, "color" : "red" }
- { "authType" : "ap1", "enabled" : true, "color" : "blue" }

**Update #2**

To summarise a few suggestions that were made...

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user[user.key].enabled }}</li>
</ul>

<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user[user.key]?.enabled }}</li>
</ul>
```

Neither of these returned anything and no errors were logged.

The following was interesting:

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user.val }}</li>
</ul>
```

This rendered the following in the component:

- function () { (0, *validation.validateArgCount)('DataSnapshot.val', 0, 0, arguments.length); return this.node*.val(); }
- function () { (0, *validation.validateArgCount)('DataSnapshot.val', 0, 0, arguments.length); return this.node*.val(); }

**Update #3**

A suggestion was made to map the call to my firebase service as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1')
                               .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And then update my component view as follows:

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
  <li>{{ user?.enabled }}</li>
</ul>
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (administration.component.ts:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:124)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Notification.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Notification.js.Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/observeOn.js.ObserveOnSubscriber.dispatch (observeOn.js:87)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/QueueAction.js.QueueAction.execute (QueueAction.js:33)
```

I also tried just dumping the whole usersData out:

```
<h3>The whole lot</h3>
{{ usersData }}
```

This rendered:

```
[object Object]
```

It's also worthwhile sharing that when I console.log what the firebase service returns, it comes back as:

[DataSnapshot, DataSnapshot]

If I expand it, you can clearly see the two array elements and their key attribute, but the children nodes aren't immediately visible but are buried deep into the structure:

- [DataSnapshot, DataSnapshot]

  - 0 : DataSnapshot

    - index_ : PathIndex
    - key: "23123123123123"
    - node_ : ChildrenNode

      - comparator_: function NAME_COMPARATOR(left, right)
      - root_: LLRBNode

        - color: false
        - key: "enabled"
        - left: LLRBNode
        - right: LLRBNode
        - value: LeafNode

          - lazyHash_: null
          - priorityNode_: ChildrenNode
          - value_: "true"
        - **proto**: Object
      - **proto**: Object
    - ref : Reference
    - ref_ : Reference
    - **proto** : Object

      - 1 : DataSnapshot
    - length : 2

      - **proto** : Array(0)

After a bit of reading online, it seems I need to create a custom pipe to convert  but I'm not sure how to go about it. The examples I've seen, firstly have errors that don't compile but are also not really clear on how it works.

Am I on the right track?

I'm still stuck on why "test 4" renders exactly what I expect and need, I just cannot access it by the attribute name (e.g. enabled, authType, etc.)?

**Update #4**

I've updated the admin.component.html with:

```
<h3>Test 5</h3>
<ng-container *ngIf="usersData != null && usersData.length !== 0">
  <ul *ngFor="let user of usersData">
    <li>{{ user?.enabled }}</li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

I've updated the admin.component.ts ngOnInit as follows and also imported markForCheck from @angular/core:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.usersData = result;
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

The console provides the following insight:

```
AdminComponent.html:32 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.es5.js:1659)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10831)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12330)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12269)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13130)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13071)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AdministrationComponent.html:32)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12236)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12601)

core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (administration.component.ts:30)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:124)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at Notification.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Notification.js.Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/observeOn.js.ObserveOnSubscriber.dispatch (observeOn.js:87)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/QueueAction.js.QueueAction.execute (QueueAction.js:33)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that also. No luck. No output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue came down to the preserveSnapshot option.

Original firebase.service.ts snippit:

```
userList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

getUsersByAuthType(authType: string) {
  return this.userList = this.afDb.list('/users', {
    preserveSnapshot: true,
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'authProvider',
        equalTo: authType
    }
  });
}
```

I needed to abandon the **preserveSnapshot: true** and set it to **false**.

admin.component.ts (no changes):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-administration',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdministrationComponent implements OnInit {
  usersData: any;

  constructor(
      private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1');
  }
}
```

admin.component.html (no changes):

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
<li>{{ user.enabled }}</li>
</ul>
```

The component renders correctly as expected. Not really sure what **preserveSnapshot: true** is an issue for the component html, but it is.

If anyone knows why this is the case, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
user[user.key].enabled
```

OR

the problem is with the type of the result. try to map your result before you call the subscribe or "async":

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1')
                               .map(res => res.json());
}
```

you don't need then the | json

you can go now like:

```
<ul *ngFor="let user of (usersData | async)">
     <li>{{ user?.enabled }}</li>
</ul>
```

use sync instead of async:

```
users: any;

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.usersData = this.firebaseService.getUsersByAuthType('ap1')
                    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(result => { 
                       users = result.users; 
                       this.ref.markForCheck();
                    });
}


<ng-container *ngIf="user != null && user.length !== 0">
   <ul *ngFor="let user of user">
        <li>{{ user?.enabled }}</li>
   </ul>
</ng-container>
```

you can now set a debugger inside the subscribe to show what type of data you are receiving. Actually, it has to work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It seemed like it may work but unfortunately, the following error resulted: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined

Comment: Sure did but this returns nothing, which makes sense given the ngFor is already iterating the object elements, so I shouldn't need (or be able to) specify the key as an array index.

Comment: Unfortunately this was unsuccessful. I've updated my post. After reading online, I get a sense that I need to create a custom pipe to deal with ngFor requiring an array rather than an object. I'm not really sure how to do that. Any ideas if this is on the right track and how to do it?

Comment: Two errors which I'll post the specifics later. First one relates to [object Object] not suitable for ngFor and the other is res.json is not a function. This is really quite frustrating and I'm wondering why this is so difficult. If the object is not an array, which ngFor needs, then could I not convert it to one with a custom pipe ?

Comment: Suspect this might be the solution... https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/05/convert-firebase-database-snapshotcollection-array-javascript/

Comment: see my last edit: use users = result.users; instead of users = result;

Comment: the problem is ( as i think ) that your json string is an json -> object (users) -> array

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate all your suggestions. I might pick this up later. Far too much effort trying to work out why Snapshot: true would cause so much additional code just to parse the json.